# Unexpectedly redirecting to root address when request URL has special character in it

Tags: redirect

I'm facing the issue after upgrading server to RHEL 8.

Here is a php script I wrote to fetch the param:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET)) {
    echo $_GET['data'];
}
```

**Now:**
When I request to the server like: https://example.com?data=test
It prints 'test' perfectly

But, when I request to the server like: `https://example.com?data="<title>test</title>"`
It redirects to https://example.com and print nothing

Can anyone suggest a solution?